# Training CNN with tfdataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to train a CNN using `TFRecordDataset` (which I think is unrelated but it's my case) and get the following error:

> ValueError: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for '{{node
> strided_slice}} = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32,
> begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0,
> shrink_axis_mask=1](Shape, strided_slice/stack, strided_slice/stack_1,
> strided_slice/stack_2)' with input shapes: [0], [1], [1], [1] and with
> computed input tensors: input[1] = <0>, input[2] = <1>, input[3] =
> <1>.

As an example, this is the code I am executing:

CNN:

```
import tensorflow as tf
def get_cnn_model(input_shape=(31, 31, 9), n_outputs=4, convolutions=3, optimizer='adam', seed=26):
    tf.random.set_seed(seed=seed)
    _input = layers.Input(shape=input_shape, name='input')
    x = layers.Conv2D(64, (4, 4), activation='relu', padding='same', name=f'conv_0')(_input)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)
    for i in range(convolutions - 1):
        x = layers.Conv2D(64, (4, 4), activation='relu', padding='same', name=f'conv_{i + 1}')(x)
        x = layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)
    x = layers.Flatten()(x)
    x = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', name='dense_1')(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(0.35, name='dropout_1')(x)
    x = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', name='dense_2')(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(0.35, name='dropout_2')(x)
    p = layers.Dense(n_outputs, activation='tanh', name='p')(x)
    v = layers.Dense(1, activation='tanh', name='v')(x)
    cnn_model = Model(inputs=_input, outputs=[v, p])
    losses = {
        "v": 'mean_squared_error',
        "p": keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
    }
    cnn_model.compile(loss=losses, optimizer=optimizer)
    return cnn_model

cnn = get_cnn_model((31, 31, 9), n_outputs=16, convolutions=3, optimizer='adam', seed=26)
```

This the sample dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

v = 0.9
p = np.random.randn(16)
state = np.random.randn(31*31*9)

sample = tf.train.Example(
    features = tf.train.Features(
        feature = {
            'v': tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[v])),
            'p': tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value = p)),
            's': tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value = state))
        }
    )
)

with tf.io.TFRecordWriter('tf_record_data') as f:
    f.write(sample.SerializeToString())
```

This is the training process where I get the error described above:

```
def read_tfrecord(example):
    feature_desc = {
        'v': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
        'p': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
        's': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32)
    }
    sample = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, feature_desc)
    x = tf.reshape(tf.sparse.to_dense(parsed['s']), (1,31,31, 9))
    y = {'v':sample['v'], 'p': tf.sparse.to_dense(sample['p'])}
    return x, y

ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(['tf_record_data'])
ds = ds.map(read_tfrecord)

cnn.fit(ds)
```

An interesting thing is when I predict over the data set, it does work:

```
import numpy as np
for serialized in tf.data.TFRecordDataset(['tf_record_data']):
    parsed = tf.io.parse_single_example(serialized, feature_desc)
    st= tf.sparse.to_dense(parsed['s'])
    t = tf.reshape(st, (1, 31, 31, 9))
    print(cnn.predict(t))
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the map for the datarecord to the following:

```
def read_tfrecord(example):
    feature_desc = {
       'v': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
       'p': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
       's': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32)
    }
    sample = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, feature_desc)
    x = tf.reshape(tf.sparse.to_dense(parsed['s']), (1,rows,cols, layers))
    p = tf.reshape(tf.sparse.to_dense(parsed['p']), (1, 16))
    v = tf.reshape(sample['v'], (1, 1))

    y = {'v':v, 'p': p}
    return x, y
```

reshaping the outputs fixed the problem